# Most effective way to use group function in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A) as a_distinct,
       COUNT(DISTINCT B) as b_distinct,
       COUNT(DISTINCT A)/COUNT(DISTINCT B) as a_b_ratio
FROM
       sometable_ab
```

As we can see this looks very inefficient as aggregate functions are run twice even though they have been calculated. I could only think of one solution to the problem that is breaking it into two queries. Is that the only probably solution. Or is their a better more efficient solution that could be done. I am using Redshift DB which mostly uses postgresql but a solution with even MYSQL would be acceptable as I cannot think of a way in any DB to do this efficiently.

Comment: *"...aggregate functions are run twice ..."* How do you know that?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' How do I get to know how it gets executed? Explain plans confuse me.

Comment: Run all query variants on a big table with [`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) a couple of times and compare best execution time to find out. You don't even need the query plan, just the execution time.

Comment: Seems like Redshift only supports basic [`EXPLAIN`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXPLAIN.html). No `ANALYZE`. You'll need another way to test execution time.

Comment: It gives an allround cost involved with a query though which does give an average sort of an idea and I have analyzed that whether I use the method in the question or a subquery I always ended up with same the cost.

Comment: I would get off redshift and use a proper PostgreSQL that said, have you considered: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html . I am pretty sure redshift can't do the things in that link but if you move to proper postgresql you should be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about the performance impact, just use a subquery:

```
SELECT a_distinct, b_distinct, a_distinct / b_distinct as a_b_ratio
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A) as a_distinct,
             COUNT(DISTINCT B) as b_distinct
      FROM sometable_ab
     ) ab
```

For most aggregation functions, this would be irrelevant, but `count(distinct)` can be a performance hog.

This is ANSI standard SQL and should work in any database you mention.

Comment: But then again this is sort of two queries... Was thinking something more subtle was available.

Comment: @Sohaib . . . This is one query that uses a subquery; it is *not* two queries.  In Postgres and (presumably Redshift), the use of the subquery makes no difference whatsoever.  Even in MySQL which materializes subqueries, you are talking about an intermediate result with two columns and two rows --  totally, totally negligible.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I ran some quick tests on PostgreSQL 9.3 locally. The two execution plans were identical except for a subquery scan.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' . . . Interesting.  That suggests that Postgres also materializes the subquery.  Performance-wise, this is irrelevant for a subquery with one row, but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So the final verdict? The query in the question and the query in your answer would perform equally because of optimizations done by Postgres?

Comment: @Sohaib . . . It is not clear if multiple executions of `count(distinct)` would show up in the query plan.  It might optimize common aggregation expressions; it might not.

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery still counts as *one* query for any RDBMS. More importantly, `count()` never returns NULL, but 0 if no row is found (or no non-null value for the given expression in any row). This would lead you straight into a **division by zero** exception. Fix it with [**`NULLIF`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) (also standard SQL). You'll get NULL in this case.

```
SELECT *, a_distinct / NULLIF(b_distinct, 0) AS a_b_ratio
FROM (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT a) AS a_distinct
        , count(DISTINCT b) AS b_distinct
   FROM   sometable_ab
   ) sub;
```